# Run Code Every Time App Opens - Better Way?

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle

I need code to run every time the app opens, including if it was only suspended (user hit home button, then returned to app).

I already know that viewDidLoad only loads on the initial VC load, so that doesn't do what I need. And viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear don't do it either. This SO thread has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175729/run-animation-every-time-app-is-opened) but it's from six years ago and I don't love the answer. Essentially, it says create an observer. However, that seems like a waste of resources and observers create those reference loops that keep things in memory.

If no one gives me a better solution I might try "applicationDidBecomeActive" in the AppDelegate, but I try not to load my appDelegate up with ViewController code.

My question is, in the six years since this SO thread was answered, do Swift/iOS10 now allow for a cleaner solution?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid putting any view controller's code to AppDelegate, however it's totally OK to forward it's methods to a view controller: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming).

Comment: Observe this https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdidbecomeactivenotification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use NSNotificationCenter Than make **global object** of your Viewcontroller in **AppDelegate**

and put code in **applicationDidBecomeActive** with your viewController object

Because **applicationDidBecomeActive** calls everyTime when you start your application and when you press home button and came from background so you don't need to write your code in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell after additional research, there's no new way since that post six years ago. However, the applicationDidBecomeActive approach does work well:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    guard let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController as? firstVCName else { return }
    rvc.nameOfMethodYouWantToCall()
}
```

The above gets a reference to the existing VC (instead of creating a whole new instance). Then it calls the method, without having to load up the appDelegate with code. Very simple and efficient.

I tested this and it's exactly what I needed, code that runs every time the app is opened. It's very consistent.